# ValueError exception "п" while reading .json file with json5

Tags: python, json, valueerror, json5

Currently, I am trying to make the simplest JSON5 reader in PyCharm that reads files from certain windows paths.

What I have encountered is a completely unknown for me error that seemingly appears out of nowhere right after I try to read a JSON5 for the 5th or 6th time.

Reading the .json goes fine until something (I'm not sure what exactly) happens and it suddenly finds a "п" out of nowhere (Ctrl + F did not give any results) and starts throwing an exception every time.

I have searched a lot of websites and found nothing useful yet or anybody else who has encountered that problem.

```
C:\Users\User\jsonTest\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/User/jsonTest/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\jsonTest\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    jsonData = json5.load(resultsFile)
  File "C:\Users\User\jsonTest\venv\lib\site-packages\json5\lib.py", line 46, in load
    return loads(s, encoding=encoding, cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
  File "C:\Users\User\jsonTest\venv\lib\site-packages\json5\lib.py", line 82, in loads
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: <string>:1 Unexpected "п" at column 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code I'm executing:

```
import json5
with open("level.json", "r+") as resultsFile:
    jsonData = json5.load(resultsFile)
```

Data from level.json:

```
{"random": 5, "data": 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the start of a Unicode byte-order mark.  You should add `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to your `open` call to have it look for the BOM.

Comment: God dang it, I knew I was missing something...
Thank you very much! It finally works now. Have a great day :D